# install python fork in docker with pipenv

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip, dockerfile, pipenv

I am trying to run my django app with docker-compose. But I get the following

```
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:12 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:12 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:12 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:12 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:13 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
web_1  |     worker.init_process()         
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
web_1  |     self.load_wsgi()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
web_1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web_1  |     self.callable = self.load()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
web_1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()           
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
web_1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
web_1  |     __import__(module)     
web_1  |   File "/code/mysite/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
web_1  |     application = get_wsgi_application()                  
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
web_1  |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
web_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
web_1  |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
web_1  |     module = import_module(entry)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaggit'
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:13 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:13 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web_1  | [2020-05-01 22:49:13 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I maintain a fork of a library at https://github.com/morenoh149/django-flaggit/releases/tag/v0.1.0
I can install it just fine in local development by doing

```
$ pipenv install
```

My Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django-flaggit = {editable = true,git = "https://github.com/morenoh149/django-flaggit"}  
...

[dev-packages]
black = "==18.9b0"
psycopg2-binary = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

I installed the fork in the past by running a command like

```
$ pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/morenoh149/django-flaggit#egg=django-flaggit
```

My Pipfile.lock in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/morenoh149/ea1abc9336d316465be54acbfb99f53a)

My docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn mysite.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=development
      - DEVELOPMENT=True
      - SECRET_KEY=asdfasdf12341234
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system --verbose

COPY . ./code/
```

Can pipenv install python package forks from GitHub when running from docker?

Comment: Please add the `Dockerfile` to the question.

Comment: Can you show the `Pipfile.lock` as well? Is it possible you did not do `pipenv lock` after adding the git package?

Comment: added the lock https://gist.github.com/morenoh149/ea1abc9336d316465be54acbfb99f53a I really think it's an issue with pip in docker pulling from GitHub. Maybe a docker network issue? I can make a sample repo if you want

Comment: instead of installing from `git = "https://github.com/morenoh149/django-flaggit.git"`, use `file = "https://github.com/morenoh149/django-flaggit/tarball/v0.1.0"`

Comment: @jakub When I make it `django-flaggit = {file = "https://github.com/morenoh149/django-flaggit/tarball/v0.1.0", editable = true, ref = "v0.1.0"}
` I get this error https://gist.github.com/morenoh149/0b06b466204684c9684f2abc6a410e09

Comment: Try to manually install it using pipenv in by running a bash in your container and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this issue was but one of our engineers provided this docker file and it works (same pipfile)

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.7 AS base

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install pipenv

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gdal-bin \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./
RUN pipenv install --deploy

# Dev image
FROM base AS dev

# Mount code as a volume to allow real time development
VOLUME /code
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 35729

ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv", "run"]
CMD python manage.py livereload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 35729 & \
  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and compose file

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 35729:35729
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```